# mi programa se ejecuta sin problemas pero todos los resultados son 0, ¿porque?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    float h, i, m, r;
    int n;

    cout << "ingrese el valor de la casa: ";
    cin >> h;

    cout << "ingrese el numero de años: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "ingrese el valor del interes: ";
    cin >> i;
    
    r = i / (100 * 12);
    m = (h * r)/ pow((1 - (1 + r)),-12);

    cout << "la cuota respectiva es "<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<< m << endl;
    /*fixed<<setprecision() sirve para definir el numero de decimales para eso es necesaria la libreria <iomanip> :p*/


    return 0;
}
```

he intentado bastantes cosas pero no logro encontrar el problema.
cabe mencionar que tengo 3 clases aprendiendo esto espero tengan paciencia
mi suposición es que tiene algo que ver con las formulas pero siento que están bien planteadas
la formula es m=hr/1-(1+r)^-12 y r=i/(100*12)

Comment: ¿Cómo sabríamos si la fórmula esta bien o mal?

Comment: Revisá la fórmula. Si querés, decinos cuál es la fmla para que podamos revisarla. Te está dando un valor muy pequeño, por eso cuando hacés el _fixed_ te termina redondeando a cero.

Comment: listo añadi las fomulas que me dio el profesor, gracias por sus opiniones

Answer (score 1):

El problema el planteamiento de la fórmula `m`
esta es la respuesta correcta:

> m = (h * r)/ (1 - (pow((1 + r),(-12* n))));